# Add a new value to a Dictionary with in a workflow

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, workflow

I need to add a new value to my `dictionary<Int32, String>` with in a workflow. The Assign activity complains that the Add method of the dictionary <> doesn't return any value.

How do I go about this?

Visual Studio 2012
Workflow Designer

Update:

No code. It on the designer. I tried Assign activity but it check if the Value portion returns something. So this became rather a general question. I have a complex workflow and in it, I need to track the audio samples collected by the system and are marked as Invalid. I need to process this collection later. Now, I can use an array as well but the issue will remain the same: How can i call the *Collection*.Add() method, which returns nothing, on the workflow designer.

Comment: You're probably doing something like `var a = dictionary.Add(some, things);` which won't work, because `Dictionary.Add()` does not return anything.

Comment: post the offending code?

Comment: @HassanGulzar - You still have not posted the code in question.  Even the designer generates code.  There has to be code causing this error.

Comment: Are there so many downvotes for this question because the OP wasn't helpful or because it was a bad question?

Comment: @BrDaHa, I don't understand it myself. The question is complete and proper as I'm not new to SO. Its not bad nor wasn't helpful. Those who understood have replied as well. I figured it out by finding the related ser of activities. No code. Its all designer.

Comment: Actually, @HassanGulzar there is code, the designer is just a visual representation of the underlying xaml. If you right-click on the file in the solution explorer, there's an option to "View Code", it should be right above the option to "View Designer". Then VS will complain that the file is open and do you want to close it, say yes, and you can see the xaml. Although, I'm not sure if posting the xaml would have helped any passers-by with your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay. I was using a custom built workflow designer and after surfing through the basic activities provided, I found four dealing exclusively with collections: `AddToCollection<T>`, `RemoveFromCollection<T>`, `ClearCollection<T>`, and `ExistsInCollection<T>`

I believe these will solve my issues. Trying out now.

Comment: And the Collection-Type activities did solved the problem. The custom workflow designer was loading only essential basic MS activites. I have to make it load the collection type activities and I was able to manage my collections.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the answer to this exact question, and I actually was about to re-post the question in hopes of improving it, but I ended up finding out the answer myself. @Hassan Gulzar if this is how you figured it out too, please mark this as the answer.

What I ended up finding out was a way to pass a single value to a dictionary collection as the argument for the AddToCollection tool in the workflow designer. Since the Dictionary class implements the ICollection interface, it can take a single value of KeyValuePair into its Add() method. So the way to use the AddToCollection tool for a Dictionary is to create a new KeyValuePair for the argument to the tool (mine might look a little different because I have to use VB.net in my workflows):
[image: Adding a key and value to dictionary in workflow]

Hope that helps someone!